# How to avoid the concurrent problem in back-end when select-then-update from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-concurrency

I'm using Java and MySQL. And I have a table:

```
create table serial_number (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment, -- PK
    sn int, -- The serial number
    available tinyint   -- 0: unavailable; 1: available
);
```

Here is the scenario:

- `SELECT id, sn FROM serial_number WHERE available = 1 LIMIT 1; -- assume the id is 1`
- `UPDATE serial_number SET available = 0 WHERE id = 1;`
- Use the serial number (sn) for other business.

How to avoid concurrent problems?

Comment: Your question is much too vague. What exactly do you want to know? What is "for other business", what is a "concurrent problem" for you? Show and explain detailed a real, concrete issue which must be solved instead of such a meaningless description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pessimistic locking or optimistic locking.

1. Pessimistic

```
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
UPDATE ... SET... WHERE
```

2. Optimistic

```
SELECT id, sn FROM serial_number WHERE available = 1 limit 1; -- assume the id is 1
UPDATE serial_number SET available = 0 WHERE id = 1 and available = 1;
```